# boostrap-tagsinput + typeahead as source doesnt work

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: 'http://mockie.dev/blog/tag/autocomplete?keyword=%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%'
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('title'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        $(".typeahead").tagsinput({
           typeahead: {
               source: engine.ttAdapter()
           }
        });
```

json return for the source:

```
[{"id":3,"user_id":1,"title":"Book Review 1","slug":"book-review","meta_keyword":null,"body":"book review","meta_description":null,"created_at":"2017-02-01 18:39:46","updated_at":"2017-02-05 13:26:05","article_counter":0}]
```

these are the js files I use:
https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js and the latest of this https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

that is all what I know, that code works on typeahead only but it doesnt when i use tagsinput and use the typeahead as source. I have been trying to fix this to work since morning, I tried boostrap-typeahead, typeahead, bloodhound. but failed to work since none of them has good documentation and "issue" section seems no one answers them on github.

i also read this http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ (typehead section) but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try typeaheadjs as the source object instead

```
$(".typeahead").tagsinput({
       typeaheadjs: {
           source: engine.ttAdapter()
       }
    });
```

Comment: can you provide the demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the engine object before tagsinput

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
        remote: {
            url: 'http://mockie.dev/blog/tag/autocomplete?keyword=%QUERY%',
            wildcard: '%QUERY%'
        },
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('title'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });

    engine.initialize()

    $(".typeahead").tagsinput({
       typeahead: {
           source: engine.ttAdapter()
       }
    });
```